# Why does the Popen() function behave differently in Python and PyGTK?

Tags: python, pygtk

I wrote these two lines in a Python program and they worked fine :

```
subprocess.Popen("./prog infile outfile >/dev/null", cwd="/path/to/prog", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

output = subprocess.Popen("prog1 infile1 2>/dev/null", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
```

However these two lines of code do not work correctly in my PyGTK application. I invoke these lines from a handler called on the "row-activated" signal of a TreeView widget. Neither does *prog* write the *outfile*, nor do I get the output of *prog1* in the *output* variable.

What could be the problem ?

---

@Sven Marnach, thanks for your inputs. I replicated the situation in a smaller PyGTK program, where Popen works just as it should.

There is no reason why Popen should have a different behaviour in a PyGTK app.

Which means I am doing something else that is creating the problem, which I will write down once fixed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygtk,sys,gtk,os,subprocess
class C:
   def main(self, argv=None):
      gtk.main()

   def __init__(self):

      # Main window
      self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
      self.window.set_border_width(2)
      self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
      self.window.connect("destroy", self._destroy_window)

      # TextView
      self.v = gtk.TextView()
      self.v.set_name("v")
      self.vsw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
      self.vsw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
      self.vsw.add(self.v)

      # TextView
      self.v1 = gtk.TextView()
      self.v1.set_name("v1")
      self.v1sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
      self.v1sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
      self.v1sw.add(self.v1)

      # TreeView
      self.model = gtk.ListStore(str, str)
      self.tv = gtk.TreeView(self.model)
      self.tv.connect("row-activated", self._f, self.v)
      self.tv.connect("row-activated", self._f, self.v1)
      self.c = gtk.CellRendererText()
      self.c1 = gtk.CellRendererText()
      self.col = gtk.TreeViewColumn("C", self.c, text=0)
      self.col1 = gtk.TreeViewColumn("C1", self.c1, text=1)
      self.tv.append_column(self.col)
      self.tv.append_column(self.col1)
      self.tvsw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
      self.tvsw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
      self.tvsw.add(self.tv)

      self.fill_model(self.model)

      # Layout
      self.rbox = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
      self.rbox.pack_start(self.vsw, False, False, 0)
      self.rbox.pack_start(self.v1sw, False, False, 0)
      self.box = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
      self.box.pack_start(self.tvsw, False, False, 0)
      self.box.pack_start(self.rbox, False, False, 0)

      self.window.add(self.box)
      self.window.show_all()

   def fill_model(self, model):
      self.dbg("fill_model()")
      model.clear()
      fd = open("file", "r"); rows = fd.readlines(); fd.close()
      for l in rows:
          a = l.split()
          model.append([l[0], l[1]])
      return

   def _f(self, tview, path, column, textview):
       self.dbg("_f()")
       tsel = tview.get_selection()
       model, iter = tsel.get_selected()
       buf = textview.get_buffer()
       buf.set_text("")
       if(textview.get_name() == "v"):
           self.dbg("_f():v")
           buf.set_text("hello")
       elif(textview.get_name() == "v1"):
           self.dbg("_f():v1")
           t = self.g()
           buf.set_text(t)
       return

   def g(self):
       self.dbg("g()")
       t = subprocess.Popen("anubadok file1 2>/dev/null", 
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
       self.dbg("g(): t = " + t)
       return t

   def _destroy_window(self, widget, data = None):
      self.dbg("_destroy_window()")
      gtk.main_quit()
      return

   def dbg(self, msg):
       sys.stderr.write("dbg: %s\n" % msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   ui = C()
   ui.main()
```

Where,

file :

```
a cat
b bat
c mat
```

file1 :

```
hello world
```

And the program [anubadok is here](http://anubadok.sourceforge.net/download.htm).

Comment: Did you make sure the handler gets actually executed, for example by adding some debug output?

Comment: Yes, the handler is called correctly. I did check.

Comment: Your directions are *really* strange.  The first line uses the shell to redirect output to `/dev/null`, but catches `stdout` anyway.  There won't be any output, it's redirected to `/dev/null`!

Comment: 1. I wasn't claiming the redirections are source of your problem.  I was just saying they are pointless. 2. I can't think of any way how removing the `> /dev/null` results in a `No such file or directory` error.  That does not seem possible. 3. Your question does not provide enough information to debug your code.  Try to create a minimal case that reproduces your error, and post the code.

Comment: did you by chance remove the shell=True parameter along with the redirection? if so, that's the reason for the OSError.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, I don't see that you wait for the child process to complete.

What is likely to happen here is that your pygtk starts a child process and exits right away, the python garbage collector destroys the Popen object.

When you run same code in python shell or some other long-running function, Popen gets more time and hopefully child process completes.

To quickly test if this is in fact the problem, try adding `time.sleep(1)` after Popen call.

What you should be doing is calling `.communicate()` on Popen object to make sure child process does its thing and terminates.

**Second**, I have come across cases when pygtk program temporarily changes working directory to something else and then changes it back.

To quickly test this case, try to supply full path both to `/path/to/prog` as well as infile, outfile, redirect, etc.

Answer (score -3):

The

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

is caused by your Popen call.  Subprocess wants a list:

```
subprocess.Popen(["./prog","infile","outfile",">/dev/null"], cwd="/path/to/prog", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: not true. Popen takes a string as well as a list. the difference lies in the `shell=` parameter.

Comment: shell=True removes the OSError.