# In a Python program, why can't I cat a file right after writing it?

Tags: python

I tried to cat a file, using Popen(), right after creating and writing to it. It doesn't work. Print p gives two empty tuples ('',''). Why ? I've used rename to ensure an atomic write, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333872/atomic-writing-to-file-with-python).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,os,subprocess

def run(cmd):
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        p.wait()
        if p.returncode:
            print "failed with code: %s" % str(p.returncode)
        return p.communicate()
    except OSError:
        print "OSError"

def main(argv):
    t = "alice in wonderland"
    fd = open("__q", "w"); fd.write(t); fd.close; os.rename("__q","_q")
    p = run(["cat", "_q"])
    print p

main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: add shell=True in you subprocess.Popen() method

Comment: @Oscar No, absolutely do not; see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641747/whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popenecho-home-and-subprocess-po

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You did not call `close`. Use `fd.close()` (you forgot the parentheses there to make it an actual function call). This could have been prevented by using the `with`-statement:

```
with open("__q", "w") as fd:
    fd.write(t)
# will automatically be closed here
```

Comment: I spent so much time trying to figure this out. Is there a way Python could have been made to detect this kind of syntax error?